# cordova not installing on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I wanted to installed ionic3 so I completely uninstalled nodejs and reinstalled it, then installed ionic,

```
C:\Windows\system32>ionic -v
3.19.0

C:\Windows\system32>npm -v
5.5.1

C:\Windows\system32>node -v
v8.9.1
```

now I am trying to install cordova and it is not installing.

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g cordova
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....1.4","ripemd160":"
^2'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DELL 5521\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-05T20_46
_55_094Z-debug.log
```

here are contents of log file

// 2017-12-05T20_46_55_094Z-debug.log
https://pastebin.com/7mVNRkC8

Comment: Ionic and Cordova should be installed with a single command `npm install -g ionic cordova`. You may want to uninstall Ionic and use that command to get them both installed. See the full details on the Ionic Installation Guide: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/installation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to uninstall ionic and cordova and reinstall them again, here are steps I did to fix it

```
$ npm uninstall -g cordova
$ npm uninstall -g ionic
$ npm cache clean -f
$ npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Answer (score 0):

try following steps 
**Ionic CLI and Cordova**
To create Ionic projects, you’ll need to install the latest version of the CLI and Cordova. Before you do that, you’ll need a recent version of Node.js. [Node Download](https://nodejs.org/en/)

next you need to open `cmd` and run `$ npm install -g ionic cordova`
learn more details https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/installation/

Comment: You can see in start of my question, I already have 3.19.0 of IONIC, npm and node are also on latest versions. Next, I am trying to install cordova as shown in question. What is the real issue?